# How do I get a DoCmd.RunSQL to properly run my script

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking for help with my error on the last DoCmd.RunSQL...
I need user input to define the values but after the user input the last RunSQL does not properly run and gives me an error or improperly deletes my data.

```
Private Sub AddModNote_Click()
     Set db = CurrentDb()
     Dim ModNo As String
     Dim ModNoT As String
     Dim ModT As String
     Dim UpQ As String
     Dim ModNum As String
     Dim SecMod As String
     Dim Equip As String
    
    
    ModNo = (InputBox("Enter in format : MOD XXX", "What is your MOD Number?"))
    ModNum = " [" & ModNo & "]"
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT SITELIST.id, SITELIST.EQP, SITELIST.[SITE NAME], SITELIST.[ORG CODE], SITELIST.SID INTO" & [ModNum] & " FROM SITELIST;"

     UpQ = "UPDATE " & [ModNum] & " SET " & [ModNum] & ".[MAT_MOD_NO]= '" & (ModNo) & "'"
     DoCmd.RunSQL UpQ
   
    'rename field names
    db.TableDefs(ModNo).Fields("id").Name = "SITELIST ID"
    db.TableDefs(ModNo).Fields("EQP").Name = "EQUIPMENT AFFECTED"
    db.TableDefs(ModNo).Fields("SITE NAME").Name = "SITE"
    db.TableDefs(ModNo).Fields("ORG CODE").Name = "ORG_CODE"


    'Alter Column
    CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & ModNum & " ALTER COLUMN [EQUIPMENT AFFECTED] Text(5)"
    CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & ModNum & " ALTER COLUMN [SITE] Text(50)"
    CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & ModNum & " ALTER COLUMN [ORG_CODE] Text(10)"
    CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & ModNum & " ALTER COLUMN SID Text(5)"
    CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & ModNum & " ALTER COLUMN MAT_MOD_NO Text(7)"
      
        EqpEntry = (InputBox("What is your Equipment Affected?"))
        Equip = "'" & EqpEntry & "'"
   
        DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete " & [ModNum] & ".[SITELIST ID], " & [ModNum] & ".[EQUIPMENT AFFECTED], " & [ModNum] & ".SITE, " & [ModNum] & ".ORG_CODE, " & [ModNum] & ".SID, " & [ModNum] & ".MAT_MOD_NO FROM " & [ModNum] & " WHERE [MOD 556].[EQUIPMENT AFFECTED]<> '" & Equip & "'"
```

I've altered the code in numerous ways at one point I believed to have it correct but I that's clearly not the case.

Any help helps!  Thank you

Comment: When you set `equip` you add single quotes to it. The string looks like `'something'`. In your sql, you then add two more single quotes to it in the code `" WHERE [MOD 556].[EQUIPMENT AFFECTED]<> '" & Equip & "'"` which will read `" WHERE [MOD 556].[EQUIPMENT AFFECTED]<> ''something''"` and that is likely throwing an error.

Comment: Thank you, That solved my problem.  I feel ridiculous!

Comment: Code-inception (so to speak) tricks us all. No reason to feel bad.

Comment: For future reference: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)